# Условия в JavaScript (if, тернарный оператор или что-то еще?)

Tags: style-guide, javascript

Есть ли возможность прописать условия более элегантно:

```
if (x2 > x1) {
  x = x1,
  w = x2 - x1;
} else {
  x = x2,
  w = x1 - x2;
}
if (y2 > y1) {
  y = y1,
  h = y2 - y1;
} else {
  y = y2,
  h = y1 - y2;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
x = Math.min(x1, x2);
w = Math.max(x1, x2) - x;
y = Math.min(y1, y2);
h = Math.max(y1, y2) - y;
```

Comment: Ну для w, h:

    w = Math.abs(x1 - x2);
    h = Math.abs(y1 - y2);

Comment: а если x1 == -2, а x2 == -1?

Comment: не важно, будет то же самое

Comment: чёрт, и правда тоже самое=)

Answer (score 1):

Не уверен, стоит ли это считать более элегантным способом, но можно так:

```
[x, w] = (x2 > x1)? [x1, x2 - x1] : [x2, x1 - x2];
```

Comment: Вы, вероятно, попутали JavaScript с каким-то другим языком.

Параллельное присваивание `[x, w] =` в JavaScript не работает.

Comment: В firefox работает

Comment: @KiTE, да ладно:
     
     var xw = (x2 > x1)? [x1, x2 - x1] : [x2, x1 - x2];
     var x = xw[0], w = xw[1];

главное смысл

Comment: @Spectre, это не параллельное присваивание. Массив из двух элементов справа не рассовывает каждый элемент в отдельную переменную слева, как, например в PHP, функция `list()`, или в Pyton, `x,y=`.

Comment: да я этого и не утверждал, и не в параллельном присвоении суть, а в том, как использовать литералы массивов и тернарный оператор, чтобы получить краткое лаконичное решение

Comment: Spectre, тогда вы не поняли суть моего первого комментария. Я критиковал именно `[x, w] =`.

Comment: я почему-то сразу подумал, что это образное выражение

Comment: Нет, это [конкретная возможность][1] в некоторых ЯП.

  [1]: http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5#.D0.9F.D0.B0.D1.80.D0.B0.D0.BB.D0.BB.D0.B5.D0.BB.D1.8C.D0.BD.D0.BE.D0.B5_.D0.BF.D1.80.D0.B8.D1.81.D0.B2.D0.B0.D0.B8.D0.B2.D0.B0.D0.BD.D0.B8.D0.B5

Answer (score 1):

Как то так :) :

```
(x2 > x1 ? function(){x = x1; w = x2 - x1;} : function(){x = x2; w = x1 - x2;})();
(y2 > y1 ? function(){y = y1; h = y2 - y1;} : function(){x = y2; h = y1 - y2;})();
```

Answer (score 0):

Тернарный оператор, как правило, применяется для условных вычислений с возвратом результата.

```
a = b>0?b:c;
```

В остальных случаях для независимых блоков кода - обычный `if`.

По крайней мере, именно такой смысл применения этих двух операторов ждет каждый программист  работающий с чужим кодом.